# Losing values in PostBack

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I had to for some reason use a hidden field to persist an Id that was originally sent to my view (a ViewModel is sent to my view with this Id).  I know I'm sending a valid Id value...that's not the issue.

So for example I'm seding in a ViewModel that has a CarId.  During runtime, I check and it's a valid integer, the same integer I passed to it from the controller's action that sent it to this view.

The issue is, since I'm not using/referencing that Id anywhere in the view's markup via Razor, I think that's why it's not persisted back during postback.  Because I notice that when I do refrence that field in markup, it's included/persisted with postback.

Even though I have this in the layout, specifying to persist the entire model itself, it doesn't persist that Id when I'm not using it in the form when it hits my Update action in the related controller:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @model = Model }))
```

So when this posts back, I have to add this or else the Id is not persisted with the other values in the ViewModel

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CarId )
```

Anyone know what I'm missing here as in fundamentals?

Comment: Yes, you need to use a Hidden. Take into account that as evil users could change that value via Firebug or something like that, you need to double chack on server side what's in that field (for example, checking if than ID is one of the valid objects of the current user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your POST action will only receive data which is actually in the form.
It doesn't magically get the rest of the model.

Note also that attackers can modify all of this data.

Comment: but even when I specify to rebind the model inside my Html.BeginForm?  I'm resetting the model type to persist through for postback so I thought.

Comment: That adds querystring parameters to the URL, but the browser drops querystring parameters before submitting the form.  You need to use hidden inputs.